# FabricJS getCircle by Id or Name

Tags: javascript, frontend, fabricjs

I am creating multiple circle objects, each with a unique name (or id).
When I want to select an object, I have to search through all circle objects and return the right object. With many objects this is not good for the performance I guess. Is there a way to select an object by a unique attribute?

I created a simple JSFiddle to show my current workaround to get a circle Object:
https://jsfiddle.net/t47vvtec/5/

I compare every object with the attribute and if one matches it, the object will be returned. Maybe you can help me to find an easier solution.

Here is my code to get an object so far:

```
function getPoint(name) 
{
    var line_point_array = canvas.getObjects('circle');

    for (var i = 0; i < line_point_array.length; i++) {
        var point = line_point_array[i];

        if (point.name == name) {
            return point;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like (https://jsfiddle.net/cssimsek/akbe97c5/1/):

```
var FabricCanvasObject = function(canvasId, attrSet) {
    this.theCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasId, attrSet);
    this.addShape = function(shapeAttrSet) {
        var newShape = this.theCanvas.add(new fabric.Circle(shapeAttrSet));
        this.canvasElements.length += 1;
        this.canvasElements[shapeAttrSet.name + this.canvasElements.length] = newShape;
    };
    this.canvasElements = { length: 0 };
};
var myFabric = new FabricCanvasObject('c', {
    targetFindTolerance: 15
});
console.log(myFabric);
myFabric.addShape({
    radius: 20,
    fill: 'green',
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    name: 'circle',
    id: 1
});
myFabric.addShape({
    radius: 20,
    fill: 'red',
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    name: 'circle',
    id: 2
});
myFabric.addShape({
    radius: 20,
    fill: 'blue',
    left: 200,
    top: 200,
    name: 'circle',
    id: 3
});
console.log(myFabric.canvasElements);
console.log(myFabric.canvasElements.circle1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think this is a better solution for me :)

Comment: You're welcome. Of course this only works for circles as I hard coded `new fabric.Circle` in the constructor function. I guess that could be modified to take any constructor using square bracket access to the `fabric` object's methods, as in `new fabric["Ellips"]()` where "Ellips" would be passed through from a new argument added to the `FabricCanvasObject` constructor..

Comment: I'm not an expert on `fabric.js`, but perhaps you may want to investigate if [fabric.Collection](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Collection.html) would solve your problem here. May offer a cleaner solution.

Comment: I will take a look at it, just fixing some other stuff at my project, but I'm hoping it will help me to improve the performance. :) thanks a lot!